# I am trying to make my inventory system work across functions in my text adventure game. I am

Tags: c#

I am using C#.

I am getting the error of:

> the name 'inventory' does not exist in the current context.

I am new at programming, and am creating this game for my final project at the university I go to. It's due in a few weeks, so I am not rushed but I like coding so I would love to figure out how to change this. My professor said I need to do my code in blocks, instead of it all being in one flowing way... this makes the local variables have problems, so I need a global of some type. I would love any help and tips.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;

namespace newGameFinal
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] inventory = new string[20];
            intro();
            gamebegin();
            gamebegin2();
        }
        public static void invalid()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input");
        }
        public static void death()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to play again? 1 for yes, 2 for no");
            string choice6 = Console.ReadLine();

            if (choice6 == "1")

            {
                Console.Clear();
                intro();


            }

            if (choice6 == "2")

            {

                Environment.Exit(0);

            }
        }

        public static void gamebegin()
        {
            {

                bool roomchoice = true;

                while (roomchoice == true)

                {
                    string room = "0";


                    if (room == "0")

                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Your goal is to survive in this dungeon....");
                        Console.WriteLine("");
                        Console.WriteLine("which room would you like to visit? (1, 2, 3, 4) 1 = South, 2 = East, 3 = West, 4 = North");
                        room = Console.ReadLine();

                    }

                    if (room == "1")

                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("You went South, you ran right into a wall. Please choose something else. (2, 3, or 4) ");
                        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------");
                        room = Console.ReadLine();

                    }

                    else if (room == "2")

                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("You went East, you went right into a Goblin... You died ");
                        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------");
                        death();
                    }

                    else if (room == "3")

                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("You went West, you saw a blinding light that shot a light spear through your chest, and you slowly bleed to death, while agonizing in pain!");
                        Console.WriteLine("");
                        Console.WriteLine("I wonder what did that. Maybe a diety of some kind?");
                        death();
                    }


                    else if (room == "4")

                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You went North, you walked into a room with many monsters...");
                        Console.WriteLine("");
                        Console.WriteLine("You can bow down to them and beg to not be killed, or quickly look for a weapon. Please type 'beg' or 'look'");
                        gamebegin2();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        invalid();
                        Console.WriteLine("Plesae choose 1, 2, 3 or 4.");
                        room = Console.ReadLine();

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //******************
        public static void intro()
        {
            player newplayer = new player();

            Console.WriteLine("What is your name...?");
            Console.WriteLine("");


            newplayer.name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine("Its dark " + newplayer.name + " I cant see anything but a dim light...");
            Console.WriteLine("");

            Console.WriteLine("You have one mission, and one mission alone " + newplayer.name + "...." + " To survive!");
            Console.WriteLine("");


            newplayer.health = 100;

            Console.WriteLine("Your health is " + newplayer.health);
            Console.WriteLine("");


            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to begin?");
            Console.WriteLine("");


            string newgame = "no";
            while (newgame == "no")
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Press 1 for Yes, or 2 for No");
                Console.WriteLine("");



                string choice = Console.ReadLine();

                if (choice == "1")

                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    break;


                }

                if (choice == "2")

                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Okay I will wait till you are");

                    newgame = "no";

                }


                else
                {
                    invalid();
                    newgame = "no";
                }
            }
        }
        public static void gamebegin2()
        {

            string choice = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

            if (choice == "BEG")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("They kill you. Should have looked...");
                death();
            }



            else if (choice == "LOOK")

            {


            }


        }
        public static void looking()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You found a dagger, do you choose to fight, or to run? Please type 'run' or 'fight'");
            string choice = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

            if (choice == "RUN")
            {

                inventory[0] = "Dagger";
            }
        }

    }
    class player { public string name { get; set; } public int health { get; set; } }

}
```

Comment: inventory is local to your Main() method. Move it to the class level so you can access it in other methods with the Program class.

Comment: And it would have to be declared static, too, since you aren't initiating anything.  Everything in your program looks like it's declared locally, so you would have to start passing these items around in parameters to talk to other functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are seeing this error is that your **inventory[]** is local to the **Main()** method.

You should move it to the class level and make it a modular variable.

```
class Program
{
    static string[] inventory = new string[20]; //Move it here and along with anything else you need to access all methods in this class
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        intro();
        gamebegin();
        gamebegin2();
    }
  //And the rest of your methods...
```